# Why does the output of this differential amplifier always get 0 V?

Tags: amplifier

I used a differential amplifier to try to get rid of the offset that came along with the desired signal.

[image]

Vcc = 5 V

[image]

In simulation everything looks good.

[image]

But when I place everything on a breadboard the output signal of the differential amplifier is always 0 V on the oscilloscope no matter what.

Every stage before that works well but when the signal gets inside this stage it drops to zero. Do you guys have any clue why?

Comment: So if the sim looks good but your breadboard is bad, what does that tell you?

Comment: Well, the Vout can't go below zero because you've got the Vee connected to ground. So if your input voltage is slightly less than Vref (give or take the offset voltage of a couple mV max) then you'll get about 0V out. If that's not what's wrong, tell us ALL the voltages on the ICs shown, accurately.